# Issues with OpenMP Parallelization of a Fortran Subroutine with Common Blocks

Tags: fortran, openmp

I find myself facing a complex issue while attempting to parallelize an old Fortran program used for Finite Element Analysis. The program is extensive, with over a thousand subroutines employing common blocks. The overarching idea is to reserve a substantial common block like XXXX(200 000000) at the program's outset, and subsequently access this data across all subroutines. Here's a snippet for better clarity:

```
    COMMON /Vector/ Vec(200000000)
    REAL*8 :: AA(n), BB(n), CC(n)
    EQUIVALENCE (AA(1), Vec(1))
    EQUIVALENCE (BB(1), Vec(n+1))
    EQUIVALENCE (CC(1), Vec(2*n+1))
```

Now, my specific challenge arises when I attempt to parallelize a particular subroutine using OpenMP to enhance overall performance. The subroutine in question involves matrix multiplication. Below is a simplified example version of the code:

```
PROGRAM MATMULT
      USE omp_lib

      common / Vector / Vec(200000000)
      INTEGER, PARAMETER :: n = 10000
      real*8 :: AA(n),BB(n),CC(n)
      EQUIVALENCE (AA(1),Vec(1))
      EQUIVALENCE (BB(1),Vec(n+1))
      EQUIVALENCE (CC(1),Vec(2*n +1))

!Init

      DO I=1, n
          DO J=1, n
              AA(J+(I-1)*n) = 1.0
              BB(J+(I-1)*n)  = 1.0
              CC(J+(I-1)*n) = 0.0
          END DO
      END DO

      CALL parallel(AA,BB,CC,NCB)

      STOP'PROGRAMM STOP'
      END

      Contains

      subroutine parallel(A,B,C,n)
         USE OMP_LIB
    
         integer :: I,J,K,n
         real*8 ::summe
         real*8, dimension(1) :: A,B,C
    
         !$omp parallel do private(i,j,k) shared(A,B,C) reduction(+:summe)  
          DO I=1, n
            DO J=1, n
        
              summe =0.0
                DO K=1, n
                   summe= summe + A((I-1)*n +K) * B(J+(k-1)*n)
                END DO
             !$omp critical
             C(J+(I-1)*n) = summe
             !$omp END critical
            END DO
          END DO
        !$omp end parallel do
       end subroutine parallel
```

Regrettably, the results are not as expected, and the values in matrix CC are incorrect. I had anticipated that all elements in CC would have the value 1000, but this is not the case.

I'm reaching out to the community seeking guidance in identifying potential issues and exploring viable solutions. I suspect there might be intricacies with common blocks and equivalence statements in conjunction with OpenMP. Any insights or recommendations would be immensely valuable.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

Regrettably, the results are not as expected, and the values in matrix CC are incorrect. I had anticipated that all elements in CC would have the value 1000, but this is not the case.

I'm reaching out to the community seeking guidance in identifying potential issues and exploring viable solutions. I suspect there might be intricacies with common blocks and equivalence statements in conjunction with OpenMP. Any insights or recommendations would be immensely valuable.
I'am using Microsoft visual studio 2019 to run my program.

Comment: I can't see how it could work, even without OpenMP. The computations assume matrices of size n*n, that is 10**8 elements, but the matrices are only n elements aparts in the equivalence statement. So, writing to C is actually overwriting parts of A and B...

Comment: By the way, common blocks and the equivalence statement are somehow deprecated in modern Fortran.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest to take the [tour] and read [ask]. Always make sure that the content (like code) in your question is displayed properly and if not, edit the question to fix it.

Comment: "Any insights or recommendations" 1) Don't ever use common. 2) Certainly don't ever use "equivalence" 3) But even more than 1) and 2) don't mix them with OpenMP - unless you enjoy a life of pain.

Comment: I really am struggling to understand your code. Over and above the issues @PierU points out the reduction of `summe` over the threads will occur at the end of the I loop. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using a lot of old features (`common`, `equivalence`), and their use is discourages nowadays. And for matrix-vector or matrix-matrix multiplication, do not try re-inventing the wheel and use the `matmult()` intrinsic function.

```
program matmult
use omp_lib
inplicit none

integer, parameter :: n = 10000
double precision, allocatable :: AA(:), BB(:), CC(:)

allocate( AA(n,n), BB(n,n), CC(n,n) )
AA(:,:) = 1d0
BB(:,:) = 1d0

call parallel(AA,BB,CC)

stop 'PROGRAM STOP'

contains

  subroutine parallel(A,B,C)
     use omp_lib
     double precision, intent(in)  :: A(:,:), B(:,:)
     double precision, intent(out) :: C(:,:)

     integer :: n, nbcol_per_thread, it, icol1, icol2

     n = size(a,1)

     !$omp parallel private(it,icol1,icol2)

     !$omp single
     nbcol_per_thread = (n-1)/omp_get_num_threads() + 1
     !$omp end single

     it = omp_get_thread_num()
     icol1 =  it   *nbcol_per_thread + 1
     icol2 = (it+1)*nbcol_per_thread
     icol2 = min(icol2,n)
     C(:,icol1:icol2) = matmul(A,B(:,icol1:icol2))

     !$omp end parallel 
     
  end subroutine parallel
```

Comment: It is only `matmul`, not `matmult`. Are you sure that this kind of manual worksharing will give the right result?

Comment: `nbcol_per_thread = (n-1)/nbcol_per_thread + 1` can't be right as it uses an uninitialized variable

Comment: I've corrected the two errors... @VladimirFГероямслава after the correction on `nbcol_per_thread`, I think that yes, it should do.